# How to Calculate the Direction of a Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let's say I have points $a$, $b$, and $c$. We also have $\vec{ab}$ and $\vec{ac}$. Finally, we  know neither vector's direction. (That is, the vector's angle on each axis as if the vector were translated so that it's tail is at (0,0,0). For example, $\overrightarrow{(0,0,0)(10,10,10)}$'s direction would be (45$\circ$, 45$\circ$, 45$\circ$). I'm not sure if that's how a vector's direction actually works, but that's how I'm using it in a program I'm writing.) So, how do I find $\vec{ab}$'s "direction?"

Comment: In my experience, it's rarely useful to compute the "direction" of a 3D vector as a separate value. What do you want to use these quantities for? There may be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @RahulNarain [3D projection...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) Or, more specifically, perspective projection.

Comment: You most definitely do not need any notion of "direction" to perform perspective projection.

Comment: "$\theta$$_{x,y,z}$ - The orientation of the camera." I'm using a vector to represent the camera. (Where the magnitude of the vector is the render distance.)

Comment: For camera angles, what is more commonly used is elevation and azimuth.  Given the origin, it takes two angles, not three, to specify a direction.

Comment: In that article, $\theta_{x,y,z}$ are not the "direction angles" of the camera. They are the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) that define the rotation matrix from world coordinates to camera-relative coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For A, maybe what you want are the [direction cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine).  In your example they will be $(\frac 1{\sqrt 3},\frac 1{\sqrt 3},\frac 1{\sqrt 3})$.  The angle between your vector and each coordinate axis is not $45^\circ$, but $\arccos \frac 1{\sqrt 3} \approx54.74^\circ$.  To find the direction cosines of $\vec{ab}$, you just take the $x,y,z$ components of $\vec {ab}$ divided by its length.

For B, you need to define the question better.  One thing would be the angle between $\vec {ab}$ and $\vec {ac}$, which you can find using the dot product:  the cosine of the angle is $\frac {\vec {ab}\cdot \vec {ac}}{|\vec {ab}|\cdot |\vec {ac}|}$.  Another would be the direction cosines of $\vec {ac}-\vec {ab}$, calculated as above.

Added:  the [azimuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth)-[elevation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevation) coordinate system is a natural one for camera pointing.  It is especially useful if you have motors to drive in these two axes.  Azimuth is the angle from some reference direction around a vertical axis, elevation is the angle up or down from the horizontal plane.  If you have motors in those axes, the angles tell you how to move them from $(0,0)$ to get where you want to go.  They also answer question B-to go from $(a_{az},a_{el})$ to $(b_{az},b_{el})$, you move by $(b_{az}-a_{az},b_{el}-a_{el})$

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand directional cosines. And I realized that I could really simplify the question by actually telling you what it is that I'm doing, rather than trying to generalize it.. Basically, I'm trying to create a vector out of two points. I just need to get the vector's direction.. Since direction is a very broad and general term, I thought that I would (in my program that I am writing which has brought about this question) define direction in the simplest, yet, for my needs, most useful (while remaining simple) way. So, I defined direction as the angles from the origin,

Comment: each angle being separate, and as if you were looking at a flattened, 2D image of it. So, back to the main point, if I had 2 points, and needed to find those angles, how would I? (In typing this, I've actually cleared-up what it is that I need, and think that I know the answer now. :P If you were to try to find the angle around the Z axis, you would just disregard the Z coordinates and solve just like in basic trig, right?)

Comment: @StevenFontaine:  The direction cosines are exactly the cosines of the angles from the axes.  You can certainly project the vector onto the $xy, xz, yz$ planes and measure the angle from one axis-that is a well defined operation.  The angles will depend on each other in ways that are hard to understand.  Whether it is useful is another question.

Comment: I'm starting to feel overwhelmed. :P Ive done kind of what I'm trying to do a few times before, and I always get confused. One thing I'm going to use this for is [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) (literally just a rotation matrix), but I need a way to find the angles required. (On the wiki page, the camera's "orientation.") I made a stupid mistake in my last comment. Literally, what I'm using this for right now is, I'm given two vectors ($\vec a$ & $\vec b$) which share a tail point. I know $a$'s direction, but not $b$'s. I need $b$'s.

Comment: @StevenFontaine:  regarding the last comment, yes, if you are looking for the angle to move around $z$ you would disregard the $z$ coordinate and look in the $xy$ plane.  That is what is usually called azimuth.  It is *very* useful to have your coordinates match the axes of motion, but there are only two of those.  The range is the third coordinate in space, and corresponds to the focus of your lens.   You might also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates

Comment: The thing is, I'm not solely talking about a camera's orientation or whatever; mainly I'm trying to figure out how to do what I said in my last comment. I have two vectors with a common tail. I know one's.. Euler angles, I suppose.. and I need to figure out the other's. (Sorry for my previous lack of terminology. I know it makes things difficult.. I'm only a junior in high school (grade 11) so I haven't learned this stuff yet..)

Comment: @StevenFontaine:  If you use az and el, the change from one vector to the other is simply the differences of the az's in azimuth and the difference of the el's in elevation.  Very handy.  They correspond to longitude and latitude on the earth.  Euler angles are for the orientation of a whole solid body, not just a vector (so you need to specify the rotation around the axis as well).  They are not well suited to taking the difference of two configurations.

Comment: Regardless of how well-suited they are, it's still what I need.. And I just need to find the rotation around the shared tail-point. So, you could imagine the tail-point to be the origin, and I would change the head-points accordingly.. And, I will eventually be applying this to solid-bodies. So, it would be nice to have a method of doing this in place, so I can just look back to it when I get to the point of applying it to solid-bodies.